# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.150)

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

Despite using compatible google chrome and chromedriver version, I recieve this error when trying to use Selenium with Python. What could be going on?

I'm using:
Selenium: 3.141.0 
Google Chrome: 88.0.4324.150 
Chromedriver: 88.0.4324.96

When I run:

```
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'D:/Downloads/chromedriver')
```

A blank google chrome window pops up and I get this printed in the console:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51885/devtools/browser/36b05e3e-3d85-4458-abed-bf242875e980
```

Then I run:

```
driver.get('https://google.com')
```

And this error pops up:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.150)
```